# Error after stopping service through Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, service, task, schedule, event-viewer

I've a running service on Windows Server 2012 called FileWatcher. It checks files into folders and does other stuff. 
I have to stop and restart the service every day at 2.00 AM so i configured two scheduled tasks: the first one stops the service at 2.00 AM, the second one starts it at 2.01 AM.

Everything is working. The service stops, then it restarts. But if I check the Event Viewer I find some errors.

- 2.00.00 AM : Service stopped successfully.
- 2.00.00 AM : Failed to stop service. System.InvalidOperationException: An unhandled exception was detected ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.
- 2.00.00 AM : Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
  Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
- 2.00.00 AM : Faulting application name: FileWatcher.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5aeae776
  Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18340, time stamp: 0x5736541b
  Exception code: 0xe0434352
  Fault offset: 0x00014878
  Faulting process id: 0x1a6c
- 2.01.01 AM Service Started Successfully.

What's going on? I mean, the service stops and restarts, why I get these errors? I already checked in another similar question, and the guy solved changing the project from Windows Application to Console Application. Mine was already Console App.

Thank you in advance, M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you repeat the error when you run / stop service by hand? Can you find the line, where this happens?

> Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.

This is a wild guess, but you have `Console.ReadKey()` somewhere in your service.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I solved it, changing from Console.Readkey to Console.Read. There is a slight difference, but in my case it did not changed the program functionality. Thank you so much!